# How to plant hydrangeas behind shrub

Tags: planting, hydrangea, boxwood

I am looking to plant hydrangeas pan bobo behind a mini hedge of boxwood green velvets. Should I elevate the soil for the hydrangeas so that they stand out more? I worry if I plant everything at the same height the boxwood hedge will simply hide too much of the plant. What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're growing the boxwood as hedging, then presumably it will be a low, clipped hedge - left to grow naturally, these shrubs will reach between 2 and 4 feet, with a similar spread, so it depends how tall you let the boxwoods grow in terms of how much you will see of the hydrangeas.

The hydrangea you mention gets 3-4 feet in height, with a spread of 6 feet or more. Because hydrangeas don't  like soil that dries out frequently or easily, raising the level at which you plant them isn't a good idea because the raised soil will dry out quicker than the surrounding soil.  So as long as you keep the boxwoods short, optimally at 1 foot, 1.5 feet max, you will be able to see the hydrangea flowers.